# Electron Beam Welding equation

Tags: nuclear-physics, electrons, coulombs-law, applied-physics

I am studying for a nuclear physics course right now and came across a question and topic that sparked my interest - Electron Beam Welding.

As I understand it, the process heats up the metal by Coulomb interactions — this allows for a high-precious weld. The question proposed though is what energy levels should the electrons be at? I know this must depend on the metal we are trying to weld. The book nor my notes provides any formula though between the relationship though.

Example: Say if I was trying to weld two thin pieces of niobium together (Z=41) what energy should the electrons be at?

Am I to get the melting point of niobium (2,469°C) and use that?

Is there a relevant formula that I can use?

Comment: The biggest issue is not the atomic energy levels, but how deep you need the electron beam to penetrate to get the weld depth you need.  Commercial e-beam welders use into the 10's of kilovolt accelerating potentials.  This is way above discrete atomic transitions, but gives you the 10's to 100's of microns of molten pool needed for a good weld.

Comment: So for the example above, would the energy level of electrons be in KeV energy range or in the MeV range?

Comment: You wouldn't want to be near an MeV electron beam. Kilovolts.

Comment: The voltage is also kept fairly low (kV) because you don't want loads of hard X-rays spraying around. The power is of course dependent on beam current (electrons per second) at a fixed accelerating potential.

Comment: So what would be the difference in electron beam strength between the metals? Would metals with fewer electron require more energy or lower?

Comment: Electron beam (EB) welding is a fusion welding process whereby electrons are generated by an electron gun and accelerated to high speeds using electrical fields. This high speed stream of electrons is tightly focused using magnetic fields and applied to the materials to be joined and tools required for welding are available on MVIKAS where I got what I was looking to work for the same.